# Error installing a .NET Windows service with InstallUtil

Tags: installation, windows-service, .net-3.5

I keep getting the error below when every I try to use the InstallUtil to install my .NET service.  I put "installutil myservice.exe" into command prompt and then get the error.  Any idea of what the problem is?  Do I need to add another parameter?

> An exception occurred during the
>   Install phase.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: The
>   source was not found, but some or all
>   event logs could not be searched. 
>   Inaccessible logs: Security.

Comment: Does your service write to the Security log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run installutil as administrator may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the NetworkService (or whatever account running the serviec) read permission on the EventLog/Security key.